# I need some help restarting this program in python

Tags: python, input, restart

```
a=random.randint(0,1000)
b=random.randint(0,1000)

goodQuotes = ["Nice job", "Keep going", "Excellent", "Great job", "You are doing great"]

badQuotes = ["You got that wrong", "Unfortunately that is incorrect", "Try again", "Retry this problem", "You made a mistake"]

while True:
  if (a > b): 
    print('What is' ,a,'-' ,b,)
    answer=int(input("Enter your answer "))
    if int(answer)== a-b:
      print(random.choice(goodQuotes))
    else: 
      print(random.choice(badQuotes))

  if (a < b): 
    print('What is' ,a,'+' ,b)
    if int(answer)== a+b:
      print(random.choice(goodQuotes))
    else: 
      print(random.choice(badQuotes))
 
  if (a == b): 
    print('What is' ,a,'*' ,b)
    if int(answer)== a*b:
      print(random.choice(goodQuotes))
    else: 
      print(random.choice(badQuotes))

retry = input("Want to try another problem, enter yes or no: ")

if 'yes' in retry:
  continue
elif 'no' in retry:
  print("Good Bye")
  break
else:
  print("Invalid Input")
```

Here is my code. I am getting an error on break and continue. My goal is to be able to rerun the program from its beginning, and I've tried putting it in a function that calls back to itself at the end, but that didn't work.  Any help to find a way to restart the program based on user input would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think continue and break should be in a loop to work.

Comment: Just indentate the last part starting with line `retry = ...` one level?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: I need to delete this post, can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is related to the tab of **if** condition and **retry** line. Also **continue** not properly in loop

Try :

```
import random
a=random.randint(0,1000)
b=random.randint(0,1000)

goodQuotes = ["Nice job", "Keep going", "Excellent", "Great job", "You are doing great"]

badQuotes = ["You got that wrong", "Unfortunately that is incorrect", "Try again", "Retry this problem", "You made a mistake"]

while True:
    if (a > b): 
        print('What is' ,a,'-' ,b,)
        answer=int(input("Enter your answer "))
        if int(answer)== a-b:
            print(random.choice(goodQuotes))
        else: 
          print(random.choice(badQuotes))

    if (a < b): 
        print('What is' ,a,'+' ,b)
        answer=int(input("Enter your answer "))
        if int(answer)== a+b:
          print(random.choice(goodQuotes))
        else: 
          print(random.choice(badQuotes))
    if (a == b): 
        print('What is' ,a,'*' ,b)
        if int(answer)== a*b:
          print(random.choice(goodQuotes))
        else: 
          print(random.choice(badQuotes))

    retry = input("Want to try another problem, enter yes or no: ")
    if 'yes' in retry:
        continue
    elif 'no' in retry:
        print("Good Bye")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
```

If you want to get new values for **a** and **b** when you enter YES to replay, you need to put them in loop as below :

```
import random

goodQuotes = ["Nice job", "Keep going", "Excellent", "Great job", "You are doing great"]

badQuotes = ["You got that wrong", "Unfortunately that is incorrect", "Try again", "Retry this problem", "You made a mistake"]

while True:
    #To get new values
    a=random.randint(0,1000)
    b=random.randint(0,1000)
    if (a > b): 
        print('What is' ,a,'-' ,b,)
        answer=int(input("Enter your answer "))
        if int(answer)== a-b:
            print(random.choice(goodQuotes))
        else: 
          print(random.choice(badQuotes))

    if (a < b): 
        print('What is' ,a,'+' ,b)
        answer=int(input("Enter your answer "))
        if int(answer)== a+b:
          print(random.choice(goodQuotes))
        else: 
          print(random.choice(badQuotes))
    if (a == b): 
        print('What is' ,a,'*' ,b)
        if int(answer)== a*b:
          print(random.choice(goodQuotes))
        else: 
          print(random.choice(badQuotes))

    retry = input("Want to try another problem, enter yes or no: ")
    if 'yes' in retry:
        continue
    elif 'no' in retry:
        print("Good Bye")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
```

Comment: I get stuck in a loop of it asking the same question over and over

Comment: Try again. i update my answer